# Numpy Problems with Arrays of poly1d Objects

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, polynomials

I'd like to first start this out with the fact that it is possible, in numpy, to create an array of `poly1d` objects:

```
random_poly = np.frompyfunc(lambda i, j: np.poly1d(np.random.randint(1, 4, 3)), 2, 1)
def random_poly_array(shape):    
    return np.fromfunction(random_poly, shape)

a1 = random_poly_array((3,3))
```

This works just fine, and we can even multiply matrices made from this form using `np.dot`:

```
a2 = random_poly_array((3,3))
a1_x_a2 = np.dot(a1, a2)
```

However, most other methods fail to work. For example, you can't take a list of certain `poly1d` objects and convert it into an array:

```
np.array([np.poly1d([1,2,3]), np.poly1d([1,2,3])])
```

As that will raise `ValueError: cannot copy sequence with size 2 to array axis with dimension 3`. To add to the confusion,

```
np.array([np.poly1d([1,2]), np.poly1d([1,2])])
```

will not raise an error, but instead create a `2x2` array of just 2's. Adding `dtype=object` has no affect, and `numpy` will still try to convert the `poly1d` objects to arrays.

---

The reason why this is problematic is that one cannot take an array of dimension *d* and convert it to an array of `poly1d` objects of dimension *d-1*. I would have expected

```
arr = np.arange(1, 10).reshape(3,3)
np.apply_along_axis(np.poly1d, 0, arr)
```

To return an array of `poly1d` objects, but instead it returns an unalterated array. Even worse, if `arr=np.arange(9).reshape(3,3)`, it will throw an error, as the first `poly1d` object created will have a length of 2 instead of 3 due to the zero coefficient. Thus, my question is this: is there a feasible method to create `poly1d` arrays in numpy? If not, why not?

Comment: You can do `np.array([None, np.poly1d([1,2]), np.poly1d([1,2])])[1:]`. Not exactly pretty but works.

Comment: That's an interesting method, and I think I figured out a way to use that to create a `poly1d` array from another array thanks to it.

Comment: Why not share it as an answer?

Comment: At first I thought it was going to be easy, but then I thought it was going to be more difficult, and then again it was easier than I expected. I just posted my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the concept of `None` forcing `numpy` to not broadcast an object into an array, something brought to my attention by [Paul Panzer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7207392/paul-panzer), I created a function which will transform the last axis into a `poly1d` object:

```
def array_to_poly(arr):
    return np.apply_along_axis(lambda poly: [None, np.poly1d(poly)], -1, arr)[..., 1]
```

However, if we're okay with abusing more than one system in a single function, we can make it apply over arbitrary axes:

```
def array_to_poly(arr, axis=-1):
    temp_arr = np.apply_along_axis(lambda poly: [None, np.poly1d(poly)], axis, arr)
    n = temp_arr.ndim
    s = [slice(None) if i != axis%n else 1 for i in range(n)]
    return temp_arr[s]
```

Testing it with `arr = np.arange(1, 25).reshape(2,3,4)`, we obtain:

```
In [ ]: array_to_poly(arr, 0)
Out[ ]: 
array([[poly1d([ 1, 13]), poly1d([ 2, 14]), poly1d([ 3, 15]),
        poly1d([ 4, 16])],
       [poly1d([ 5, 17]), poly1d([ 6, 18]), poly1d([ 7, 19]),
        poly1d([ 8, 20])],
       [poly1d([ 9, 21]), poly1d([10, 22]), poly1d([11, 23]),
        poly1d([12, 24])]], dtype=object)

In [ ]: array_to_poly(arr, 1)
Out[ ]: 
array([[poly1d([1, 5, 9]), poly1d([ 2,  6, 10]), poly1d([ 3,  7, 11]),
        poly1d([ 4,  8, 12])],
       [poly1d([13, 17, 21]), poly1d([14, 18, 22]), poly1d([15, 19, 23]),
        poly1d([16, 20, 24])]], dtype=object)

In [ ]: array_to_poly(arr, 2)
Out[ ]: 
array([[poly1d([1, 2, 3, 4]), poly1d([5, 6, 7, 8]),
        poly1d([ 9, 10, 11, 12])],
       [poly1d([13, 14, 15, 16]), poly1d([17, 18, 19, 20]),
        poly1d([21, 22, 23, 24])]], dtype=object)
```

as expected.